# Is it possible to do an Ajax request for an ICS file?

Tags: jquery, ajax, request, icalendar

I am trying to do an Ajax request for an ICS file. Yeah, I know it sounds crazy, but I found the perfect library to parse the iCal data. Any ideas why the data comes up blank when I do this?

```
$.ajax({
 success:function(data){
  alert(data);
 },
 url:"http://wsidecar.apple.com/cgi-bin/nph-reg3rdpty2.pl/product=15714&cat=98&platform=osx&method=sa/Swiss32Holidays.ics"
});
```

It makes the request fine, but the data still comes up blank.

** Is it a datatype error?

Comment: try this http://homepage.mac.com/ical/.calendars/Swiss32Holidays.ics

Comment: Still nothing. A look at Chrome's resource (content) page for the file shows up blank. Mime issues?

Comment: Honestly doesn't even look it's making the request.

Comment: hm... i looked at source code in your link - there redirect to webcal://ical.mac.com/ical/Swiss32Holidays.ics and i changed `webcal:` to `http:` and I see 'BEGIN:VCALENDAR
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-WR-TIMEZONE:Europe/Paris
PRODID:-//Apple Inc.//iCal 3.0//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN...'

Comment: Tried it (in Chrome) still nothing, weird?

Comment: I'm using opera 10.5. Have you looked source code or tested it in script?

Comment: In script? Source code? Of course. The problem is that it won't load the ICS contents in Chrome. It appears as if it's redirecting the file then refusing to load it, weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, you can't load content from another domain through .ajax().

Comment: You are right. I proxied the content over. I thought this only applied to JSON but I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

try with dataType: "text". It you will have no success then try usage of dataFilter(data, type) function.